# Insert items missing from TableB Into TableB based on items existing in TableA

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

I have two tables: TableA - a list of default items.  TableB is a copy of TableA, but may have items missing.  I need an insert statement that inserts the missing items into TableB

```
TableA

Key varchar(10)

Rows:
Key1
Key2

TableB 
Key varchar(10)

Rows:
Key1
```

How to Select all missing items from TableA and insert into TableB?  In other words, insert Key2 into TableB.

Using Sql Server 2008R2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use **LEFT JOIN**

```
INSERT INTO TableB ([key])
SEECT a.[key]
FROM TableA a
LEFT JOIN TableB b
 ON a.[key] = b.[key]
WHERE b.[key] IS NULL
```

Answer (score 0):

This should go though TableB and overwrite any blank or null items in key2 based on what is in tableA (if tableA has blanks or nulls that would be a different story)

```
update TableB b
set b.key2 case b.key2
    when ' ' then
        select key2 from tableA where a.key1 = b.key1
    when null then
        select key2 from tableA where a.key1 = b.key1
```